# Multiple vs Single app for mobile (currently android) devices

Tags: android, performance, mobile, scalability, multi-tenant

I'm working on an android project in which there are two works. Let call works as W1 and W2. There are also two kinds of users let it be U1 and U2. So, U1 needs to handle both W1 and W2(but less frequently) and U2 will only work on W2 and has nothing to do with W1. The apps will run offline but will sync few times a day.

My doubt is that should I create two different (android) application (one for U1 which can do W1 + W2 work and other for U2 which will contain only W2 features) or one application with a two different login will work as well(one application with both features W1 and W2, U1 and U2 type login, can provide different accessibility)? Please take scalability issues into consideration along with performance issues. Is **Multitenancy** possible on mobile apps?

Few major points:-
1) I'm talking about mobile(currently android) apps only.

2) W1 is 80% of code and have a complex database structure

3) W2 is 20% of the code and have a simple database structure

4) U1 do W1 work most of the time and do W2 rarely.

5) U2 only work is W2 and will never use W1.

6) App mostly works in offline mode and sync few times a day to the server.

Answer (score 0):

There are benefits and issues at the same time ... let us talk about one application instead two.

- As a programmer this is going to be not a good idea if there is no interact between to apps + as a programmer your code must be clear to can modify it again if you want to improve it after a long duration.
- at the same time if we are going to talk about user this process of login two times with different applications in one that is not efficiently at all.

**NOTE : This is just my opinion**